# Change HTML button value on pageload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have a login page and I am storing the localStorage key's value i.e. username taken from login page to a variable using `var unameVar=localStorage.getItem('uname')`. Now I want to assign the value of `unameVar` to a button. To put it short the button's name should be that of `unameVar` on page load. Need help on this

*javascript*

```
<script>
    var unameVar=localStorage.getItem('uname');;
    console.log(unameVar)
</script>
```

*html*

```
<button class="btn btn-link" > This value needs to be changed                    
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` to the button then after retrieving value from localStorgae, use `text` from jquery library to add text

```
$('#buttonID').text(unameVar.trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) function and pass the new value from `localStorage`.

```
let unameVar=localStorage.getItem('uname');
let button = document.querySelectr('button');

/*When Page is loaded completely*/
window.onload = function(){

   button.innerText = unameVar; //=====> Assing your localstorge value to button
}
/*-----------------------------*/
```